# Обновить данные в базе если они "старее" 15 секунд

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая задача, выбрать данные из таблицы, если они не старше 15 секунд. Если же старше 15 секунд, то вставить новые. Подскажите новичку, как правильно оформить переменную "сейчас минус 15 секунд". Вот демонстративный упрощённый код:

```
(SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id=1);
if ( test_table['time'] < "сейчас минус 15 секунд" ) { 
Не делать ничего.
} else if ( test_table['time'] > "сейчас минус 15 секунд" ) {
UPDATE 'test_table' SET 'test_row' = 'test_text' WHERE 'id'= 1;
}
```

где time - это MySQL TIMESTAMP, который вставляется автоматически с каждым INSERT'ом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

такие вещи надо делать прямо в sql запросе

вот это должно обновить все данные старше 15 секунд:

```
UPDATE 'test_table' SET 'test_row' = 'test_text' 
WHERE 'id'= 1 and `time` < date_sub(now(), interval 15 SECOND)
```

вот так, по идее должны обновиться данные только за последние 15 секунд:

```
UPDATE 'test_table' SET 'test_row' = 'test_text' 
WHERE 'id'= 1 and `time` 
BETWEEN 
timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 SECOND)) AND timestamp(NOW())
```

иначе вы делаете один запрос на селект в базу данных, вычисления в коде и один запрос на апдейт.

в правильном варианте вы просто засылаете данные в базу и она делает апдейт если нужно.

Comment: к сожалению нужно всё делать в php, так как данные, которые вносятся в таблицу, должны генерироваться непосредственно пользователем на особых, выделеных для этого приватных ссылках, которые заносятся в базу и потом на этой же приватной ссылке эти данные и выводятся ...

Comment: эмм, данные из базы вы в php получаете и обрабатываете их в базе, пользователь здесь не при чем. Все операции (и php и mysql) происходят на стороне сервера.

Comment: тоесть я могу сейчас вставить свои переменные в этот код и они будут работать ?

Comment: ну ты проверь.  если бы ты показал show create table для таблиц, используемых в запросе, можно было бы проверить, а так, прости, хз. Но, допустим, в хайлоаде селект и дополнительная проверка на стороне php просто не применимы, за это увольняют.

Comment: @BimBam Ну так вы и продолжаете делать в php, просто ваш `if` выполняется на стороне БД в виде условия в where, которое проверяет время. И интересно откуда время в БД берется, из БД небось и берется. А часики то на машине с БД и машине с программой могут и разойтись и тогда ваш if на стороне php будет нерабочим. А БД со своим единым временем гораздо лучше справится

Comment: @Mike хорошее замечание, кстати. Правда, я не завидую этим самым,  у которых эксплуатация не следит за синхронизацией времени на серверах. Но да. Со временем нае6очки случаются