# Обновление объявления (повышение в списке) php sql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Цель: сделать обновление объявлений, например список из 10 объявлений, расположенных по порядку:
1
2
3
..
10
Нажимаем "обновить" на 10 и оно становится первым:
10
1
2
..
9

Решение: идея в том, чтобы сортировку сделать по дате (по убыванию), и при нажатии "обновить" записывалась текущая дата

Проблема: проблема в том, что нужно сделать ограничение на обновления (раз в неделю). Думал как-нибудь скрывать кнопку, но найдутся "умники", которые будут обновлять через запрос.

В общем у кого какие мысли на этот счёт? Сам новичок, поэтому ничего в голову не лезет.

Comment: У вас дата обновления есть. Так берите разницу с текущей датой и если меньше недели, то запрет обновления.

Comment: Не подскажете как это реализовать в mysqli?

Comment: Ответ близкий по смыслу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530691/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-15-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4/530693#530693 + другие вопросы/ответы с выборками по периодам из базы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmysql%5d%20INTERVAL

Comment: Не получается отнять время, ничего не выводит. Помогите кто составить правильный запрос 
mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'UPDATE `agrousadby` SET `date` = NOW() 
WHERE `id` = '.$Param['id'].' `date` < date_sub(now(), interval 7 DAY))');

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, '
UPDATE `agrousadby` 
SET `date` = NOW() 
WHERE `id` = '.$Param['id'].' 
AND `date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
```

Вдруг кому-то пригодиться)